# set transaction\query timeout through django?

Tags: django, heroku, timeout, django-orm

Is there a way to set a timeout in django for db transactions or for db queries executed via django's ORM?

**A sample use-case:**
Heroku limits django web requests to 30sec, after which Heroku terminates the request without allowing django to gracefully roll-back any transactions which have not yet returned. This can leave outstanding transactions open on databases such as postgres. You could configure a timeout in the database, but that would also limit non-web-related queries such as maintenance scripts analytics etc. In this case setting a timeout through django ([or via the middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19963954/348545)) would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

For postgres clients there is a configuration parameter called `statement_timeout`. Good thing: it can be set through environment variables.

That means if you set `PGOPTIONS` to `--statement-timeout=28s` in your heroku settings for this app, the statement will fail after 28s.

To keep in mind: this setting then will be used for all dyno types, not only your webservers.

If you want to fix this, you can add the config to your `Procfile` (with  python example):

```
web: PGOPTIONS=--statement-timeout=28s waitress-serve myapp.wsgi:application
worker: PGOPTIONS= worker.py
```

Then only connections from your webserver will have this statement timeout.