# set transaction\query timeout in psycopg2?

Tags: heroku, transactions, timeout, psycopg2

Is there a way to set a timeout in [psycopg2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2) for db transactions or for db queries?

**A sample use-case:**
Heroku limits django web requests to 30sec, after which Heroku terminates the request without allowing django to gracefully roll-back any transactions which have not yet returned. This can leave outstanding transactions open on postgres. You could configure a timeout in the database, but that would also limit non-web-related queries such as maintenance scripts analytics etc. In this case setting a timeout via the middleware ([or via django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19963854/348545)) would be preferable.

Answer (score 52):

You can set the timeout at connection time using the options parameter. The syntax is a bit weird:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> cnn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test options='-c statement_timeout=1000'")
>>> cur = cnn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("select pg_sleep(2000)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
psycopg2.extensions.QueryCanceledError: canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

it can also be set using an env variable:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PGOPTIONS'] = '-c statement_timeout=1000'
>>> import psycopg2
>>> cnn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test")
>>> cur = cnn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("select pg_sleep(2000)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
psycopg2.extensions.QueryCanceledError: canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

Comment: Just a note, the syntax needs the trailing 's' character after the integer value if you want to use seconds as the unit: '-c statement_timeout=10s' for 10 seconds. Otherwise it treats the value as milliseconds I believe.

Comment: @piro : What's the default value for `statement_timeout` ?  In my version of postgres (9.3) it's set to 0, which looks to me like postgres will let the query run essentially forever lol.  Does `psycopg2` work the same way by default?  I know this is an old thread but thanks :D

Comment: @dmn: yes, by default postgres doesn't set any statement timeout. The default can be changed per database (in the config file), per user (ALTER USER ... SET statement_timeout), per connection (as per response above), per session or query (using SET or SET LOCAL). psycopg just uses whatever the server defines, or the customer is configured with, or the connection string configures, it doesn't add anything of its own.

Comment: Related question - is it possible to set a timeout on the connection rather on per statement basis?

Comment: @KarlAnka you might be looking for idle_in_transaction_session_timeout

Answer (score 14):

You can set a per-statement timeout at any time using SQL. For example:

```
SET statement_timeout = '2s'
```

will abort any statement (following it) that takes more than 2 seconds (you can use any valid unit as 's' or 'ms'). Note that when a statement timeouts, psycopg raises an exception and it is your care to catch it and act appropriately.

Comment: nice to know, however using this per statement would incur an overhead

Comment: This setting is not per statement, this setting applies to all statements made on the connection (or cursor, not sure) after it.

Comment: use SET LOCAL for per-transaction settings or SET SESSION for per-session https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-set.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like PostgreSQL 9.6 added idle transaction timeouts. See:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT for reference.
- http://blog.dbi-services.com/a-look-at-postgresql-9-6-killing-idle-transactions-automatically/ as an example.

PostgreSQL 9.6 is also supported in Heroku so you should be able to use this.